# Where does IProcessHostPreloadClient parameter values come from?

Tags: .net, iis

Looking at IProcessHostPreloadClient's Preload method, there is a string[] parameter which may be provided, described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.iprocesshostpreloadclient.preload.aspx) as "Data to initialize the application".  However, there is no information on where this data comes from, or how we might assign values to it.

Where does this data come from, and how can we assign values to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked me the same question. I found this answer from http://www.houseofmorten.com/geeky/dotnet/-net-framework-4-0-readme :

> The System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient.Preload method takes
>   a string array as an input parameter. However, there is no way to set
>   this data, and no information is ever passed in this parameter.
>
> To resolve this issue:
>
> Earlier preview versions of the IIS 7.5 autostart feature supported a
>   way to configure one or more string values to pass to the ASP.NET 4
>   IProcessHostPerloadClient.Preload method. However, that functionality
>   was removed before the final release of Windows 7 and of Windows
>   Server 2008 R2.